# $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R $ is continuous. $ A = \{ T > 0 : f(x+T) = f(x) , \forall x \in \Bbb R \}$ not empty. Prove $f$ is constant $\iff$ $inf A=0$.

Tags: real-analysis, supremum-and-infimum

**Problem**: Let $ f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R $ be continuous s.t. the set $ A = \{ T > 0 : f(x+T) = f(x) , \forall x \in \Bbb R \} $ isn't empty. Prove $ f $ is constant $ \iff $ $ inf A = 0 $.

**Attempt:**
$ (\rightarrow ) $ [ I managed to prove this direction ].

$ (\leftarrow ) $ Suppose $ inf A =0 $. We want to show that $ \forall x,y \in \Bbb R $ s.t. $ x\neq y $ that $ f(x) = f(y) $. Suppose for the sake of contradiction that $ \exists x',y' \in \Bbb R . x' \neq y'$ so that $ f(x') \neq f(y') $. Assume WLOG $ f(x') < f(y') $. Since $ inf A =0 $ then there exists a sequence $ ( x_n) \subset A $ s.t. $ \lim x_n = 0  $. [ Now I'm stuck and don't know how to proceed ].

Can you please help me as to how do I continue my proof? My intuition breaks down and I can't see what can I do next in order to help me in my proof - how would you also recommend getting an intuition for how to continue the proof?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is not constant then there is some $x_0$ such that $f(x_0)\ne f(0)$. Let $|f(x_0)-f(0)|=\epsilon>0$. Since $f$ is continuous at $0$, we have:

$\exists\delta>0 \ \ (\forall x: |x|<\delta)\ \ [\ \ |f(x)-f(0)|<\epsilon]$

In paricular, if $x\in [0,\delta]$ then $f(x)\ne f(x_0)$. So now we will show that if $0<T<\delta$ then $T$ doesn't belong to the set $A$. (which will obviously imply that $\inf(A)>0$). So let $0<T<\delta$ and suppose that $T\in A$. Note that for $m=\lfloor\frac{x_0}{T}\rfloor$ we have $x_0-mT\in [0,T]\subseteq [0,\delta]$. As we have seen, this implies $f(x_0)\ne f(x_0-mT)$. But this is contradicting the assumption $T\in A$.

Comment: Why if $x\in [0,\delta]$  then this means $ f(x) \neq f(x_0) $ ?

Comment: Because $x\in [0,\delta]$ implies $|f(x)-f(0)|<\epsilon$, while $|f(x_0)-f(0)|=\epsilon$. So we can't have $f(x)=f(x_0)$.

Comment: Nice proof, how did you have the intuition about what to do though? especially after where you said " if $ x\in [0,\delta] $  then $ f(x)\ne f(x_0) $ ".

Comment: The intuition here is clear. If we have $f(0)\ne f(x_0)$ then by continuity at $0$ we must have $f(x)\ne f(x_0)$ when $x$ is very close to $0$. And this means $f$ can't have very small periods. Indeed, if it has a very small period $T$ then we can start moving from $x_0$ to $0$ with steps of length $T$. If $T$ is very small it means after a finite number of such steps we will have to come close to $0$, and so we will get a point $x$ which is close to $0$ and satisfies $f(x)=f(x_0)$, a contradiction. The whole question is how to write this idea formally, and that's what I did in the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is correct until now, keep going !

Hint 1 : If f is T periodic, then it is $n*T$ periodic for all natural positive number n.

Hint 2 : $\Bbb R$ is archimedian, so for all $a,b>0$, there is a number k such that ka>b, and even a least number such that it hold, so $ka>b\geq (k-1)a$.